# How System.out.println() works in java?

Tags: java, arrays, excel, for-loop

In the below mentioned code i am trying to get data from a excel sheet and store them inside an array. I have written the code to get data from a excel file inside my ReadExcelData method. Now problem which i am facing is inside my main method when i print the data by using the array the data is getting printed multiple times. I found that since i have used System.out.println() inside two for lop thats why it is getting printed multple times. To solve this i removed the System.out.println() (Comment- In the below code the bold System.out.println() is the one which i removed ) from the ReadExcelData method and once i did that i was not able to get any output. Please tell me what i should do to get the data from the ReadExcelData only once without printing it because i want to print the data in my main method.

```
package com.selenium; 
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class ReadExcelData {
 static String[] data = new String[15];
  public String getData() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException{
   String data="Initial";
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\ScreenShot\\Excel.xls");
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
    Workbook work = WorkbookFactory.create(input);
    Sheet sheet = work.getSheet("Data");
    int rownum=sheet.getLastRowNum();
    //System.out.println("Row number = "+rownum);
     for(int i=0;i<rownum+1; i++){
       Row row=sheet.getRow(i);
       if(row != null){
           for(int j=0; j<row.getLastCellNum();j++){
       //System.out.println(row.getLastCellNum());
        if(row.getCell(j) != null){
             data = row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
             if(data != null){
                    **System.out.println(data);**
            }//if2
        }//if1
           }//for2
       }//if3   
     }//for1
     return data;
 }//getdata


public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException{
  ReadExcelData read =new ReadExcelData();

  for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
         data[i]= read.getData();
      }

  }//main
}//class

Code block which is giving problem- 
 if(data != null){
                    **System.out.println(data);**
            }//if2
```

Comment: `read.getData` reads all the data from `Excel.xls` and prints it.  Your main program calls `read.getData` 15 times.  What did you think would happen when you called it 15 times?

Answer (score 1):

you are calling your method in loop:

```
 for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
         data[i]= read.getData();
      }
```

So it is printing multiple time.

If you want to put all the values in data[] then you shall do following changes

```
public String[] getData() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException{

    String[] data = new String[15];
    ...

    int k =0;
    ...

    String cellVal = row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
    if(cellVal != null){
        data[k++] = cellVal;
    }//if2

    ....

    return data;
}
```

And from main method call it only once:

```
String[] excelData = read.getData();
```

Comment: Actually i want to get i string data inside one array i.e, data[1]= 1 Value, data[2]= 2nd Value. But froblem is i am not able to do so. Can you please tell me how to do it? if(data != null){
                    **System.out.println(data);**
            }//if2. And i want to know what exactly System.out.println(data); working inside the loop because when i remove this the program only prints the last cell data from the the excel file

Comment: @SwetaSingh apply above mentioned changes to your code. it will do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: By doing that can i get each cell data separetly. Like excelData[1]= some value, excelData[1]= some other value

Comment: Yup, try that @SwetaSingh

Comment: One Last question- What exactly the System.out.println() in the secong loop working because once i removed it the program stops execution.

Comment: `System.out.println` does not do any special thing it just `prints whatever is input to the console with a new line at the end`. Your program does not stop execution after removing that. it just stops printing to console.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, for each cell of your Object data, you're calling the methode that fills it.
You have:

```
    data[i]= read.getData();
```

and then you have your method called 15 times, opening, reading and returning the entire file 15 times.

Just remove the loop from your main, and everything will work as you want.